# disable wp-pagenavi on pages with template using the wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

How can i disable wp-pagenavi on pages using templates and the wordpress loop? It seems that wp-pagenavi adds itself automatically wherever the
wordpress loop is used, not counting that it is a page or not.

Comment: You might want to try wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Has your question been answered here or have you found an answer elsewhere?

Comment: @Christopher Found the solution later and forgot to come back to stack. Fixed now. :-) If you're interested in the solution check the comment to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have `wp_pagenavi()` in the footer.php file.

if you don't want it to appear in the page.php you can do this.

```
<?php if(!is_page()) { ?>

// if it is not a page echo the page navigation

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

<?php } else { ?>

// if it is a page do nothing or you can specify.

<?php  } ?>
```

but i'm not quite sure of what you mean by page template. if i'm wrong give me the details on that.

good luck

Comment: wp_pagenavi() call is automatically inserted by the plugin (not manually by me)..maybe the best way is to manually do so myself. The problem is wp-pagenavi lacks the option to disable automatic insertion. For Page Templates check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) link. Another issue is if i use is_page() that will make navigation not show up on pages using custom templates using the loop to show posts and what i want is to show that navigation on certain such pages and not on others.

Comment: Indeed.. after a deep inspection the theme files were calling wp_pagenavi(). Now all that was left to do is remove the call from the custom page templates as needed.